# Setting extremes sometimes results in unwanted padding left and right

Tags: highcharts

I use Highcharts to render graphics from seismic measurements. I set the data manually through CoffeeScript/JavaScript via JSON data that is rendered from the backend.

The options for the chart are:

```json
{
  "width": 770,
  "height": 250,
  "spacing": [0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

The options for the xAxis are:

```json
{
  "minPadding": 0,
  "maxPadding": 0,
  "startOnTick": true,
  "endOnTick": true
}
```

I add the data as follows:

```coffee
# 'c' references a Highcharts chart object

# I add the series
c.addSeries({ data: response.data.x }, false)

# I set the extremes
hmin = response.extremes.h.min  # i.e. 0.0
hmax = response.extremes.h.max  # i.e. 6.23
c.xAxis[0].setExtremes(hmin, hmax, false)

# ...
# set some other options, like chart title, etc
# ...

# finally I redraw
c.redraw()
```

However, depending on the rendered data, I sometimes (more often than not) get a padding in the plot area left and/or right.

[image]

The desired output should ALWAYS be no padding/empty on either side and the chart should end at 6.23 in the above example.

What am I missing?

Edit: Here's a [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qcvepb5h/3/) for testing.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: I could and added the JSFiddle link above. Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like is done here? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/062oucrd/

Comment: Hmm... this still has an empty space at the right for me? I would like for the series to be plotted across the entire area with no whitespace left or right. Is this only achievable with positioning ticks manually, maybe?

Comment: what about this configuration? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uv65n0ap/

Answer (score 0):

- Padding appears because you set the chart width manually - `width:770` at line #15. You can remove that line or specify percent as the width value.
- The xAxis is ending with 7 because you set the axis option- `endOnTick:true` at line #43. You should remove this line to end the xAxis in hmax.